# Geometric series : Find common ration 'r'

Tags: geometric-series

**Find common ration of a finite geometric series**
If the first term is 11 and sum of first 12 terms is 2922920.

After applying the formula I got
$265720 = (1 - r^{12})/(1-r)$ but I don't know how can I solve for it further.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether an analytical solution like you probably expect is possible. What I would do instead is: $$265720 = \frac{r^{12} - 1}{r-1} $$
$$265720 \approx \frac{r^{12}}{r} = r^{11} $$
$$r \approx 3$$
And then verifying that $3$ actually satisfies the equation.