# Knowing the sum, can I solve a finite exponential series for r?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know a geometric expression can be written down as:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{k-1} = \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}
$$

Is it possible to solve this for r, knowing the total sum? (how about if you know the last value in the sequence instead of the first? - to me intuitively this would just result in r becoming 1/r)

Comment: For practical purposes in my case, I am allowed to assume that r is rational and >0. But I suspect @Robert Israel is correct and it would not change the answer to this question.

Comment: For others interested, I found a small discussion on this topic from more than 2 decades ago: https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/questionCorner/sumtoratio.html

Comment: And for people looking for the pragmatic approach: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473457/how-to-find-r-in-a-finite-geometric-series

Comment: So do you know $n$ too?

Comment: Just to be clear; are $a$ and $n$ given?

Comment: They would be given, but I was interested in the (im)possibility of a general formula/approach where _a_ and _n_ are given. I realize if I actually substitute for _a_ and _n_ , some simplification options could emerge depending on the specific value of _a_ and _n_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\sum_{k=1}^n a r^{k-1} - y$ is a polynomial in $r$ of degree $n-1$, typically irreducible over the rationals.  In general it may not be solvable in radicals.
For example, try $n=6$, $a=1$, $y=3$: $r^5 + r^4 + r^3 + r^2+r - 2$ has Galois group $S_5$ (according to Maple) and is not solvable in radicals.  Of course numerical solution methods can be used: the real root is approximately $0.7090111952$.

EDIT: If you are looking for rational roots, the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) lets you reduce the problem to finitely many possibilities. It changes things completely. Why didn't you mention that in the first place?

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible since the summation is not injective in general, for example

$$\sum_{k=1}^{3} r^{k-1}=7 \implies r=2\;\lor\;r=-3$$

Comment: Although you have considerably narrowed the range of possible $r$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Do you refer to the value $r=1$?

Comment: I mean that you've gone from any real number (or complex number, if desired) to a finite set of real (complex) numbers, which is still useful information.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Oh yes of course! I'm assuming implicitely that $r$ is real! Thanks